# Which script language interpreters will work on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scripting

For an App that is not going to be released on the AppStore I'm looking to embed an interpreter for easy scripting needs. Since I don't really like to get down with pure C, the interpreter should be an Objective C library.

While searching the web I've come across a couple of script interpreters for Objective C but whether those guys work on iPhone is not quite so clear. The one I found that apparently works well on iPhone is [LuaCore](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/LuaCore) which brings Lua scripting to iOS Apps.

Which Objective C scripting interpreters have you successfully embedded in iOS Apps?

Comment: As a follow-up to my own question, I've discovered the following link detailing a Lua / iPhone integration: http://www.grzmobile.com/blog/2009/12/1/integrating-lua-into-and-iphone-app-part-2.html

Comment: One more Lua pointer: http://www.mobileorchard.com/announcing-iphone-wax-native-uikit-iphone-apps-written-in-lua/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Javascript options:

1. Using a [headless WebKit](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2012/02/11/Using-UIWebview-as-a-JavaScript-Interpreter.html) instance
2. Instantiate a [custom build of JavaScriptCore](http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/06/javascriptcore-project-files-for-ios)
3. CouchBase's attempt at getting [SpiderMonkey](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iMonkey) running (more modern Javascript than V8)

Notice that the JS option will provide with a quite raw runtime environment, you'll probably need to write at least some of it yourself for it to be a convenient development environment.

Other languages:

4. An attempt with [Python](https://github.com/cobbal/python-for-iphone).
5. [Clojure](http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/2011/07/using-clojure-for-ios-apps/) by way of a static build of `JavaScriptCore` (see point **2** above).
6. The [Nu](http://programming.nu/index) language is also supposed to integrate well, and have a good Objective-C bridge.

I have only tried the first headless WebKit variant for Javascript, but plan to try as many of those listed as possible for a project during the coming months.

**Update:**
I've used the Javascript method **1** (headless WebKit) a bit longer. I got it running quite effortlessly, and will stick with that for a while. But it has a huge drawback: you can't call back to native in an easy manner. I solved this by writing a [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) inspired bridge that empties a command queue after the script has run.

I've also tried Python using the link I gave. I made it compile and execute some sample code, but it suffers from the same problem as using Js via headless WebKit, and since it consumes quite a bit of memory I skipped it for now. A callback command queue in the same spirit as the one I created with Js would be possible though. Another Python method would be to attempt to call into the Objective C runtime using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html). That approach is described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1490644/288672) answer.

**Update 2:** [Here](http://maitria.com/scheme-on-mobile.html) are several new(ish) links for running [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)), with both interpreter and compilation options.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon a [really decent description](http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2010/07/tweak-away/) by Twitter user [@mysterycoconut](http://twitter.com/mysterycoconut) of how to get Lua support up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered a post regarding [scripting on iOS at answerspice.com](http://www.answerspice.com/c119/1630216/examples-of-interpreters-embedded-in-iphone-applications).

Based on the post I evaluated [Nu](http://programming.nu/) and had it up and running pretty quickly based on the Xcode project referenced in [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/programming-nu/browse_thread/thread/b6a97719bdfd1035#) (thanks Tim!). I tested in the simulator and on an iPhone 4. So Nu is definitely among the scripting languages that can be embedded in an iOS App.