# Using Python libraries in objective-c app

Tags: python, ios

I've only used objective-c and I saw that Python has some libraries for calculating some map data.  I found this post about Python in iOS apps: 
[Embedding Python in an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691655/embedding-python-in-an-iphone-app)

I was wondering if it's possible to include these libraries and use them to calculate map data in an iOS app.  Thanks!