# Compile Python Code In Objective-C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

I have seen multiple iPad apps that can run simple Python code from an app.  I just wanted to know how they do this.  I know it is possible to run Python code embedded in an iOS app but I am confused as to how.  Is there any library that would allow me to run embedded Python code?  I would also like to know what PyObjC really does because I have not seen a full build or what objp does. This question is different than the one previously asked [here] ([Embedding Python in an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691655/embedding-python-in-an-iphone-app)) because it is about running python in an app.  I want to know if it is possible/how to write python code in a text field of sorts and run that.  I have seen apps in which this functionality is possible the python app for iOS does exactly this.  How can I make my own version, or at least make something that can compile and run python code.

Comment: In order to run Python code from a string, you need to embed a Python interpreter. That's what the linked question tells you how to do.

Comment: That is basically all I wanted you are a lifesaver thank you.