# How to make Python speak

Tags: python, text-to-speech

How could I make Python say some text?

I could use Festival with subprocess but I won't be able to control it (or maybe in interactive mode, but it won't be clean).

Is there a Python TTS library? Like an API for Festival, eSpeak, ... ?

Comment: does "Festival" have a public API?

Comment: For text to speech I found this package called **"[gTTS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gTTS)"** in Python. You can try this out. It does work with Python 3.5. The github repo for this package is [gTTS-github](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should try using the PyTTSx package since PyTTS is outdated. PyTTSx works with Python 2. For Python 3, install the PyTTSx3 package.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx/

https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/

Comment: Does not work for python 3. This answer was up to date as of 2009

Comment: Despite being available through pip, still does not work as of 2015

Comment: I confirm it does not work with python3 and easy fixes (printf as a function, fixing exception handling syntax and fixing imports) don't make it work, it simply fails silently. Interfacing with espeak (what it does on Linux) is as simple as spawning a subprocess, so that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Just added a comment eat the top of the question to note this only works with Python 2.x

Comment: PYTTSX3 works in python 3 too. Its a cool module

Answer (score 43):

A bit cheesy, but if you use a mac you can pass a terminal command to the console from python.

Try typing the following in the terminal:

```
$ say 'hello world'
```

And there will be a voice from the mac that will speak that. From python such a thing is relatively easy:

```
import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")
os.system("say 'hello world'")
```

Comment: I don't want the `say` command to block my Python code, so I add an ampersand like this: `os.system("say 'hello world' &")`

Comment: On ubuntu, the terminal command to use is [`spd-say`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/spd-say.1.html)

Answer (score 35):

install
pip install pypiwin32

### How to use the text to speech features of a Windows PC

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

speak = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak

speak("Ciao")
```

### Using google text-to-speech Api to create an mp3 and hear it

After you installed the gtts module in cmd:
pip install gtts

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os    

tts = gTTS(text="This is the pc speaking", lang='en')
tts.save("pcvoice.mp3")
# to start the file from python
os.system("start pcvoice.mp3")
```

Comment: You can install required module in your system by running `pip install pypiwin32` as administartor.

Comment: Google solution seems to be one of the best : allows to change of language, it is also really fast.

Comment: Strangely, the first code example works on some Windows 10 PCs but not others. Why is that?

Comment: @ColorCodin I am not sure, but you should check in the control panel, the syntetized voice (I don't remember the exact name of this options) and see if it has been set... there is a button you can press to see if it works. If it works in the settings, should work with the code, because I think it uses the windows synthesized voice, I think.

Comment: It's been set, but when the command is run through CMD it says "Access is denied."

Comment: did you installed pip install pypiwin32 as administrator (as suggested by Kamil Szot?)?

Answer (score 16):

The [python-espeak](https://launchpad.net/python-espeak) package is available in Debian, Ubuntu, Redhat, and other Linux distributions.  It has recent updates, and works fine.

```
from espeak import espeak
espeak.synth("Hello world.")
```

Jonathan Leaders notes that it also works on Windows, and you can install the mbrola voices as well. See the espeak website at http://espeak.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 10):

A simple Google led me to [pyTTS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncassist/files/), and a few [documents about it](http://mindtrove.info/articles/synthesizing-speech-with-pytts/). It looks unmaintained and specific to Microsoft's speech engine, however.

On at least Mac OS X, you can use `subprocess` to call out to the `say` command, which is quite fun for messing with your coworkers but might not be terribly useful for your needs.

It sounds like Festival has a few public APIs, too:

*Festival offers a BSD socket-based interface. This allows Festival to run as a server and allow client programs to access it. Basically the server offers a new command interpreter for each client that attaches to it. The server is forked for each client but this is much faster than having to wait for a Festival process to start from scratch. Also the server can run on a bigger machine, offering much faster synthesis.* [linky](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/festival_28.html)

There's also a [full-featured C++ API](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/manual/festival_28.html#SEC132), which you might be able to make a Python module out of (it's fun!). Festival also offers a pared-down C API -- keep scrolling in that document -- which you might be able to throw `ctypes` at for a one-off.

Perhaps you've identified a hole in the market?

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of ways to make Python speak in both Python3 and Python2, two great methods are:

- Using os

If you are on mac you will have the os module built into your computer. You can import the os module using:

```
import os
```

You can then use os to run terminal commands using the os.system command:

```
os.system("Your terminal")
```

In terminal, the way you make your computer speak is using the "say" command, thus to make the computer speak you simply use:

```
os.system("say 'some text'")
```

If you want to use this to speak a variable you can use:

```
os.system("say " + myVariable)
```

The second way to get python to speak is to use

- The pyttsx module

You will have to install this using

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

or for Python3

```
pip3 install pyttsx3
```

You can then use the following code to get it to speak:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say("Your Text")

engine.runAndWait()
```

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 7):

#### PYTTSX3

**What:**

**Pyttsx3** is a python module which is a modern clone of pyttsx, modified to work with the latest versions of Python 3!

- **GitHub:** https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3
- **Read the documentation**: https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.org

**Why:**

It is **multi-platform**, **works offline**, and **works with any python version**.

**How:**

It can be installed with `pip install pyttsx3` and usage is the same as pyttsx:

```py
import pyttsx3;
engine = pyttsx3.init();
engine.say("I will speak this text");
engine.runAndWait();
```

Comment: Is there a recommended way to make saying async?

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev No there doesn't seem to be one. Just use asyncio or however you do that in python I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **espeak** using python for text to speech converter.
Here is an example python code

```
    from subprocess import call
    speech="Hello World!"
    call(["espeak",speech])
```

P.S : if **espeak** isn't installed on your linux system then you need to install it first.
Open terminal(using ctrl + alt + T) and type

```
    sudo apt install espeak
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the Google Text To Speech library because it has a more natural voice.

```
from gtts import gTTS
def speak(text):
  tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
  filename = "voice.mp3"
  tts.save(filename)
```

There is one limitation. gTTS can only convert text to speech and save. So you will have to find another module or function to play that file. (Ex: playsound)

Playsound is a very simple module that has one function, which is to play sound.

```
import playsound
def play(filename):
  playsound.playsound(filename)
```

You can call playsound.playsound() directly after saving the mp3 file.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be anything 'Python specific', but the KDE and GNOME desktops offer text-to-speech as a part of their accessibility support, and also offer python library bindings. 
It may be possible to use the python bindings to control the desktop libraries for text to speech.

If using the Jython implementation of Python on the JVM, the [FreeTTS](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php) system may be usable.

Finally, [OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489800/getting-list-of-mac-text-to-speech-voices-programmatically/1490611#1490611) and [Windows](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/93025/) have native APIs for text to speech. It may be possible to use these from python via ctypes or other mechanisms such as COM.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python 3 and windows 10, the best solution that I found to be working is from Giovanni Gianni. This played for me in the male voice:

```
import win32com.client as wincl
speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.Speak("This is the pc voice speaking")
```

I also found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSSsVhoR7FQ&index=22&list=WL&t=183s) on youtube so if you really want to, you can get someone you know and make your own DIY tts voice.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work with other languages (Japanese or Chinese?)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for. A complete TTS solution for the Mac. 
You can use this standalone or as a co-location Mac server for web apps:

http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/ttsserver/

Answer (score 0):

Combining the following sources, the following code works on Windows, Linux and macOS using just the `platform` and `os` modules:

- [cantdutchthis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18428496/7496549) for the mac command
- [natka_m's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-to-make-python-speak#comment104337539_18428496) for the Ubuntu command
- [BananaAcid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647762/7496549) for the Windows command
- [Louis Brandy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/7496549) for how to detect the OS
- [nc3b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2756755/7496549) for how to detect the Linux distribution

```
tx = input("Text to say >>> ")
tx = repr(tx)

import os
import platform

syst = platform.system()
if syst == 'Linux' and platform.linux_distribution()[0] == "Ubuntu":
    os.system('spd-say %s' % tx)
elif syst == 'Windows':
    os.system('PowerShell -Command "Add-Type –AssemblyName System.Speech; (New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer).Speak(%s);"' % tx)
elif syst == 'Darwin':
    os.system('say %s' % tx)
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Operating System '%s' is not supported" % syst)
```

Note: This method is not secure and could be exploited by malicious text.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this simple code in python.

Works only for windows OS.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def speak(text):
    speak = Dispatch("SAPI.Spvoice")
    speak.Speak(text)

speak("How are you dugres?")
```

I personally use this.