# python assign variable, test, if true skip else, if not re-assign variable

Tags: python

pulling hair out. (sorry frustrated)

ok, so i'm trying to do an if: else in python, only i can't get it to work properly so i'm hoping that someone can help.  i'll try and be as specific as possible.

what i'm tring to do ->
i'm assigning a variable to check if something is true, sometimes it is sometimes it's not.

if that variable is true then i want it to skip the else statement and print out the result. (once fully implemented it will return resutlt to script instead of printing)

python code:

```
import re

os_version = open('/etc/os-release')
for line in os_version:
    OS = re.search(r'\AID_LIKE=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)
    if OS:
        print(str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID_LIKE="'))
    else:
        OS = re.search(r'\AID=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)
        print(str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID="'))
```

when i run it like this i get a NoneType object has no group

if i have an if OS: statement indented under the else, before the print, then i get both results back, even if i have a 'break' after the first print

depending on what platform of linux that i'm running on will depend on what the results should be.

example (bash code)

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR0=`cat /etc/os-release | grep -w ID_LIKE | cut -f2 -d= |\
    tr -d [=\"=] | cut -f1 -d' '`
VAR0="${VAR0:=`cat /etc/os-release | grep -w ID | cut -f2 -d= |\
    tr -d [=\"=]`}"
echo $VAR0

if [ "$VAR0" = 'debian' ]; then
    echo 'DEBIAN based'
elif [ "$VAR0" = 'rhel' ]; then
    echo 'RHEL based'
elif [ "$VAR0" = 'suse' ]; then
    echo 'SUSE based'
else echo 'OTHER based'

fi
```

this is the return that comes back from the bash code->

```
bash -o xtrace os-version.sh 
++ cat /etc/os-release
++ grep -w ID_LIKE
++ cut -f2 -d=
++ tr -d '[="=]'
++ cut -f1 '-d '
+ VAR0=rhel
+ VAR0=rhel
+ echo rhel
rhel
+ '[' rhel = debian ']'
+ '[' rhel = rhel ']'
+ echo 'RHEL based'
RHEL based
```

from a different os->

```
bash -o xtrace test_2.sh 
++ tr -d '[="=]'
++ cut -f1 '-d '
++ cut -f2 -d=
++ grep -w ID_LIKE
++ cat /etc/os-release
+ VAR0=
++ tr -d '[="=]'
++ grep -w ID
++ cut -f2 -d=
++ cat /etc/os-release
+ VAR0=debian
+ echo debian
debian
+ '[' debian = debian ']'
+ echo 'DEBIAN based'
DEBIAN based
```

as you can see the VAR0 on the first run is empty and it then goes to the second.

that's what i'm trying to do with python.

can someone help?  i have a feeling that i'm just overlooking something simple after starting at the screen for so long.

thanks

em

edit for joel:

my code now and the results=>
code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

os_version = open('/etc/os-release')
for line in os_version:
    OS = re.search(r'\AID_LIKE=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)
    if OS:
        print(str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID_LIKE="'))
        break
    else:
        OS = re.search(r'\AID=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)
            if OS:
            print(str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID="'))
```

results from a debian system=>

```
python test.os-version_2.py 
debian
```

results from a debian based system=>

```
python test.os-version_2.py 
raspbian
debian
```

results from centos7=>

```
python test.os-version_2.py 
centos
rhel
```

results from opensuse=>

```
python test.os-version_2.py 
opensuse
suse
```

results from linuxmint(what i'm running now, even though it's ubuntu/debian basied)=>

```
python test.os-version_2.py 
linuxmint
```

so since some things are responding differently and there are so many different distro's based off of a couple, i'm trying to narrow down the results to the fewest possible.

each one has a different way that they do things and to try and get a script that is cross platform working as best as it can, i'm trying to narrow things down.

if you 'cat /etc/os-release' you will see that different os's display things differently.

edit answer:

i don't know why this is yet for me putting a variable to the print statements and then printing the variable it's working.  maybe someone can answer that for me.

answer code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

os_version = open('/etc/os-release')
for line in os_version:
    OS = re.search(r'\AID_LIKE=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)#.group()
    if OS is not None:
        base_distro = (str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID_LIKE="'))
    else:
        OS = re.search(r'\AID=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)#.group()
        if OS is not None:
            base_distro = (str(OS.group()).lstrip('ID="'))

print(base_distro)
```

if you put that into a script and then run it you will see what i'm looking for.

thanks everyone for helping

Comment: i should add that i'm somewhat new to this stuff.  can read programming pretty well, yet can't get my brain to write it.

Comment: Could you clarify which line is giving the error? It's almost certainly that your OS variable is unexpectedly set to None, and/or your "print" indentation is off.

Comment: you are trying to get linux distro name, so check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2756737/1040495

Comment: Jjpx, i looked at that and it's somewhat on the right track.  yet as the commenters have said, that's depreciated.  didn't run it since i'm trying to get this running under 3.x

Comment: You're assuming the system _has_ an `/etc/os-release` file.  Not all Linux systems do.

Comment: that is true. maybe i should just look at the log dir to find what i'm looking for. i know what/where the big three keep what i'm looking for. i just thought finding what distro the running system is based on would be less overhead in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the system platform is easy with Python 2.7 see [platform import](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/how-to-use-the-platform-module-in-python)

```
import platform

print platform.dist()[0],type(platform.dist()[0])
```

returns

```
debian <type 'str'>
```

On my platform.

To clarify - 
`OS = re.search(r'\AID_LIKE=\D[A-Za-z]+', line)` 
returns an object (NoneType)

Note "import platform" will be depreciated. Below is method with the new way (just a basic method, might not be suitable to all situations, but it works for what i think you have described - to do your comparisons, just use a `dict` like in the comments

Edit - Super simple way - using subprocess if platform doesn't work

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["cat", "etc/os-release"])
with open('text.txt', 'w+') as fd:
    fd.write(output)
with open('text.txt', 'r') as text_output:
    for os_version in text_output:
       try:
           print os_version.split("ID_LIKE=",1)[1]
       except:
           continue
```

Here we just call the actual command, take the output as a string, chuck it in a file, and read all the lines, splice the line at the key word we want and bam! Want the OS ID? Then add `print os_version.split("ID=",1)[1]`

Again the output is:
debian
raspberry pi

Comment: try that on a centos, opensuse distro.  what i'm trying to do is to narrow down what the base os is, i.e. debian, red hat, suse, other maybe.

Comment: Adding `platform.uname()[1]` will return the OS - for my case raspberrypi

Comment: on centos7=>>>> import platform
>>> print platform.dist()[0],type(platform.dist()[0])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print platform.dist()[0],type(platform.dist()[0])
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: to expand on what i'm trying to do:    if i'm trying to say where to look for something depending on what named distribution that you are running then i have to say-> if debian, then, elif/or raspberry, elif/or ubuntu, elif/or linuxmint, elif/or rhel, elif/or centos, elif/or fedora, elif/or.....   if i can narrow it down to the big three right away, wouldn't that be just that much easier?

Comment: @ementib  Deciding what to do based on exactly matching one of a set of strings is _exactly_ the kind of problem a `dict` solves: `os_map = {'debian': deb_func, 'rhel': rh_func, 'fedora': rh_func, ...}`  Then, just `os_map.get(os_name, generic_func)(arg0, arg1, ...)`.

Comment: Official [`platform` module's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html).

Comment: @ementib i have added an edit with some other code - again tested on my Pi