# How to get the operating system information from python docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

Docker images can inherit from other images. Therefore, using the official Python docker image allows running Python applications and tools.

```
docker run --rm -it python bash
```

After creating and running an interactive container from the [python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) image, I would like to print the Linux distribution information.

```
lsb_release
```

However, the `lsb_release` command is not found. According to the documentation, it used the Debian distribution as the base image. How can I get the exact distribution information?

Comment: Your Docker image is probably built `FROM` a fixed base, and a typical setup will `RUN` installation commands for any external OS commands that are needed, so when your application runs you should know exactly what's there.  Is there a reason you need to look this up dynamically?  Also see [Check Linux distribution name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756737/check-linux-distribution-name) if the application needs to run in several environments and the distribution name specifically matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Python image supports different operating systems and architectures. Find *OS/ARCH* information by releases at https://hub.docker.com/_/python/tags. Click on a specific *DIGEST* link for more information.

The official Ubuntu Docker image does not have `lsb_release`. An alternative command to retrieve the distribution information:

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/476485/do-some-debian-builds-not-have-lsb-release

Comment: I'll just add that for a Python image, at the interactive Python shell, you can quickly check the same info with `import subprocess; _ = subprocess.run("cat /etc/*release", shell=True)`