# Capturing TTS output in Python

Tags: python, text-to-speech

What I'm trying to achieve is to save a text to speech output from Python to an audiofile.

Well the only constraint is Python version 2.7 (would be cool if it runs on Windows and ubuntu, but not necessary). I found pyttsx and managed to have a text read but I can't capture it because there is no method like in pyTTS SpeakToMemory. Well pyTTS is just available for Python 2.5. I can't use that either.

**How can I make a text to speech and save it in an audio file with python 2.7?**

Comment: I can't really figure where your problem lies, could you provide a little more insight on your issue?

Comment: well in short the question is: how can I make a text to speech and save it in an audio file with python 2.7...

Comment: @ele, this seems like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-tomake-python-speak. Does the answer to that question answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the link.. As I mentioned above I already tried pyttsx and pytts (like mentioned in your link) but i can't figure out how to save it to wav under Python 2.7 - either it does not work under python 2.7 at all (pytts) or it cant save it to a file (pyttsx)

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892199/detect-record-audio-in-python

Comment: @F.C. Thanks for the link... He is recording from microphone. I tried to make it record from my python app but it didnt work...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to create audio from text with google text to speech API

First install gtts from cmd
pip install gtts

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts = gTTS("Hello","en")
tts.save("hello.mp3")
```

and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies it's ok if this is a Mac OS X only solution? If so, then you can modify the Mac OS X driver in pyttsx (pyttsx/drivers/nsss.py) and give it the ability to call the  `startSpeakingString:toURL:` method on the NSSpeechSynthesizer class:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This will save synthesized text to a file.