# How to convert text into audio file and play in browser via python/django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, text-to-speech

How to convert text into audio file which can be played in browser via python/django views?
How can I do text-to-speech conversion in python? I want to convert a string to a .wav file, that will be played in a browser via python/django views.

For example:

```
text = "how are you?"
convert text to audio file (text.wav)
open text.wav file & play in browser via django view.
```

Comment: You will need some kind of text to speech engine. An open source engine is festival: http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: There's also a js text-to-speech program called [speak.js](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js)

Answer (score 0):

As [Tichodroma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/647772/tichodroma) says, you should always see if someone has already asked your question before asking it again.  Google search for `python text to speech` returns http://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/ and [How to make Python speak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-tomake-python-speak), among others.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do like following way & it works for me. Thanks.

```
#Write text to file
text_file_path = '/user/share/project/test.txt'
audio_file_path = '/user/share/project/test.wav'
text_file = open(text_file_path, "w")
text_file.write('How are you?')
text_file.close()

#Convert file
conv = 'flite -f "%s" -o "%s"' % (text_file_path, audio_file_path)
response = commands.getoutput(conv)

if os.path.isfile(audio_file_path):
    response = HttpResponse()
    f = open(audio_file_path, 'rb')
    response['Content-Type'] = 'audio/x-wav'
    response.write(f.read())
    f.close()
    return response
```