# How can I make Python speak with mbrola?

Tags: python, mbrola

I need to create a `Python` program, which will speak the numbers chosen randomly. Like, `Python` gives me number 11, and with `mbrola`, it says "eleven". It's very simple, I've created almost everything, but the only thing I need is - make `Python` speaks it using `mbrola`!

Please, could you give me some examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Python speak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-to-make-python-speak)

Answer (score 1):

There is a python module called `pyttsx` which speaks things. You can install it by using `pip install pyttsx` and then use it as such

```
import pyttsx as tts
engine = tts.init()
engine.say('Eleven')
engine.runAndWait()
```